# Does Apache Solr assign a weight to HTML tags?

Tags: 7, search

Would Solr consider HTML tags when it creates its indexes? Would `<h1>`, for example, be more important than `<h2>`, `<p>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Apachesolr module, then yes. The module has some sensible weighting defaults for the tags, but they can be further customized at `admin/settings/apachesolr/query-fields`.

Comment: How did I miss that! thanks, no wonder Google search were not coming back with anything when it is so simple.